# Apache Spark: Can't save Grouped Data as CSV

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I wanted to do a simple thing. I wanted to bucket all event counts into timestamps of say 2 minutes.

It works fine.

```
df = df.groupBy(window(df["time_value"], "2 minutes")).count()

df.show()

+--------------------+-----+
| window|count|
+--------------------+-----+
|[2018-04-10 15:00...| 770|
|[2018-04-10 00:42...| 100|
|[2018-04-10 04:14...| 54|
|[2018-04-06 15:54...| 36|
|[2018-04-10 04:46...| 304|
|[2018-04-10 20:36...| 347|
|[2018-04-10 03:26...| 41|
|[2018-04-10 21:10...| 85|
|[2018-04-10 11:44...| 426|
|[2018-04-10 12:32...| 754|
|[2018-04-10 00:28...| 61|
|[2018-04-10 05:36...| 478|
|[2018-04-06 07:04...| 18|
|[2018-04-10 22:14...| 195|
|[2018-04-10 23:40...| 175|
|[2018-04-10 00:20...| 229|
|[2018-04-10 03:10...| 209|
|[2018-04-10 01:28...| 67|
|[2018-04-09 18:52...| 9|
|[2018-04-10 19:06...| 3548|
+--------------------+-----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

But now that I write it,

```
df.write.csv("good_loc.csv")

An error occurred while calling o161.csv.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CSV data source does not support struct<start:timestamp,end:timestamp> data type.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVUtils$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$csv$CSVUtils$$verifyType$1(CSVUtils.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVUtils$$anonfun$verifySchema$1.apply(CSVUtils.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVUtils$$anonfun$verifySchema$1.apply(CSVUtils.scala:131)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.foreach(StructType.scala:98)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVUtils$.verifySchema(CSVUtils.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat.prepareWrite(CSVFileFormat.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:145)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeInFileFormat(DataSource.scala:437)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:473)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:609)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:217)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:597)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 766, in csv
self._jwrite.csv(path)
File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
return f(*a, **kw)
File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
format(target_id, ".", name), value)
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o161.csv.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CSV data source does not support struct<start:timestamp,end:timestamp> data type.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVUtils$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$csv$CSVUtils$$verifyType$1(CSVUtils.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVUtils$$anonfun$verifySchema$1.apply(CSVUtils.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVUtils$$anonfun$verifySchema$1.apply(CSVUtils.scala:131)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.foreach(StructType.scala:98)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVUtils$.verifySchema(CSVUtils.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat.prepareWrite(CSVFileFormat.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:145)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeInFileFormat(DataSource.scala:437)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:473)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:609)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:217)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:597)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I can't understand why the error is coming. I already created the dataframe, I just showed it and it showed fine. Now, I am just trying to save it in a csv, don't get what is happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You column `window` is an StructType. Therefore, you cannot write it directly as a CSV. You need to flatten it a little bit. Either cast it to string, or explode its structures, in 2 columns `start` and `end`. CSV can only have "simple" types like string, interger or timestamp.

try this :

```
df.select(
    'window.start',
    'window.end',
    'count',
).write.csv("good_loc.csv")
```

Comment: I had another issue..the window function just gives values like )):42 to 00:44 and if there is not data between 0:44 to 0:50 then it just doesn't show that there were zero events in that time.. I want it to show all the time intervals and give the number of events in them..is there any way to do it in spark..in pandas it was so easy..just resample

Comment: @Rafael you need to `join` with the missing data. The `groupBy` cannot generate the missing data. But that is another problem. Please create another topic for that.

Comment: isn't there any way to do it without join? for that i will have to create days worth of data then join..tedious..any spark time series libraries to help?

Comment: @Rafael not in spark as far as I know. The easiest way is to generate your dates in python, then export in spark and join probably.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot write an Array type to CSV. Convert/change the field window (**Array**) to window (**String**) before saving.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def array_to_string(my_list):
    return '[' + ','.join([str(elem) for elem in my_list]) + ']'

array_to_string_udf = udf(array_to_string,StringType())

df = df.withColumn('window-stringified',array_to_string_udf(df["window"]))
```

Then you can drop the old column (array type) before saving.

```
df.drop("window").write.csv(...)
```